# How to add an already serialized bytebuffer to a builder that is creating a vector of tables?

Tags: flatbuffers

I am working in Java with Flatbuffers. I have a vector of tables, something like :

```
table T2 {
    property : [T1];
}

table T1 {
    field1 : int;
    field2 : int;
}
```

So,records of T1 were already serialized and the ByteBuffers are cached in, say, Redis. When I retrieve them(ByteBuffers) back from redis, I want to add these records to T2 and create a vector of tables. Since all these T1 records are already serialized, I want to know the most efficient way to build the flatbuffer T2. I think I can create it by adding each T1 by accessing their fields and creating new objects. I believe this may not be the most efficient way to achieve this. I am hoping if there is a way to directly add the serialized bytebuffers of T1 to the builder and get their corresponding offsets to pass to the `.createvectorOfTables()` method.

Comment: This question was already asked and answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flatbuffers/UZmDyIxIzZY

Answer (score 1):

From your mentioned scenario, it looks like you want to handle two different buffers. In that case it would be better to keep it that way in schema. Can try:

```
table T2 {
   property: [T1Buffer]; // Stores the buffer 
}

table T1Buffer {
tBuff: [ubyte];
}

table T1 {
field1: int;
field2: int;
}
```

Now, when you are done writing your T1, just push the obtained buffer in T1Buffertable, and now create array of these buffer tables.
During read, you can get each T1Buffer and then deserialize independently.